# saving to grails using a specific id/email

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have two domains, Patient and Allergy. I want to save allergies particular to the specific patient(email is the unique identifier for each patient). The details are coming from an android app and email is one of the parameters.

Assuming a user already exists, how would I go about the allergy service to be able to do this.

This is the patient service which successfully registers a new patient and saves their details. I have a controller which acts as an API for the android app.

```
@Transactional
class PatientService {



   //creating new
    def updateSave(params) {
        def patient
        //record exists
        if(params.id){
             patient = Patient.findById(params.id)
            if(patient) {
                patient.validate()

                patient.dateUpdated = new Date()
                patient.save(params)
            }
        }else{


            params.password=MD5CodecExtensionMethods.encodeAsMD5(params.password)


            patient = new Patient(params)
            patient.validate()

            System.out.println(patient.errors)
            patient.save flush:true


        }

        return patient
```

Here is what I have tried with allergy service but am stuck

```
@Transactional
class AllergyService {


def  Save(params) {
    def allergy
    Patient patient




        allergy = new Allergy(params)
        allergy.validate()

        System.out.println(allergy.errors)
        allergy.save flush:true

    return Allergy.findAllByPatient(params)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the `Patient` has many `Allergies`, so you have to create an appropriate association:

```
class Patient {
    static hasMany = [allergies: Allergy]
}
class Allergy {
}
```

Grails will automatically inject a Set of allergies into the Patient domain.

In your `save` method, you should have access to `Patient` or his `email` property in order to connect them somehow.
Then, you can do like:

```
def save(patientEmail, params) {
    Patient patient = Patient.findByEmail(patientEmail)
    Allergy allergy = new Allergy(params)
    patient.addToAllergies(allergy)
    patient.save()
}
```